# c program functionality confusion

Tags: c, mplab

I'm pretty new to c programming and I have this following program to degub. Problem is, I have no idea what these lines of code even mean. Could anyone point me in the direction of what they mean as far as from a syntax point of view/functionality? ***What does the code do?*** The code is compiled with MPLab C30 v3.23 or higher.

```
fractional abcCoefficient[3] __attribute__ ((space(xmemory)));    /*ABC Coefficients loaded from X memory*/

fractional controlHistory[3] __attribute__ ((space(ymemory)));    /*Control History loaded from Y memory*/

fractional kCoeffs[] = {0,0,0};     /*Kp,Ki,and Kd gains array initialized to zero*/
```

Comment: This is not standard C, You should indicate the compiler you are using and update the tags accordingly.

Comment: The code is compiled with MPLab C30 v3.23 or higher

Answer (score 2):

These lines declare variables; there's no execution code associated with what you've pasted.

The environment this code is intended for understands that `fractional` is a type; either in the same file or in a header this file includes (directly or indirectly), `fractional` will be defined with a `typedef` statement. In your examples, each of the variables are arrays of three `fractional` types.

The `__attribute__ ((space(?memory)))` entries are attributes the compiler intended to build this understands and affect something regarding how the variables are managed. You'll want to consult the compiler documentation for the platform you're using.

Answer (score 1):

See [this page](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Attributes.html) to learn about `__attribute__` in gcc (however, I don't see a `space(xmemory)` option in there, consult your compiler's documentation if it's not gcc. If it is, then `space()` can be a macro).
`fractional` is also a custom type, search for `typedef` definitions for fractional.

Basically, the code is creating a bunch of arrays of type `fractional`. The first two make use of gcc's attribute extension (or whatever compiler you are using), and the last one is initialized to 0 on every position.

Comment: Bad luck this is not GCC

Comment: @hivert Yep, had that feeling when writing my answer. Do you know what it is?

Comment: It looks like it's some embedded system ide. But I don't know anything about.

Comment: @hivert these two documents: [1](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/70094E.pdf) and [2](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/70238b.pdf) may help, searching for MPLab as the OP indicated may help more.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like "fractional" is a custom type, look for its typedef somewhere and it should get you started on what you're looking at. I expect these are variable declarations.

Macros are established using the "#define" preprocessor directive, so you can look for "#define space(x) code" somewhere to tell you what it does. Good luck.

Comment: No they are not variable initialization. See http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Attribute-Syntax.html

Comment: I stand corrected. I thought "__attribute__" looked familiar.

Comment: So please delete your post or fix it to avoid downvote.

Comment: I've edited out the part about space() being used for initialization.

Comment: there is a good chance that `space()` is not a macros but something very specific to the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

The first two lines declare arrays with three elements each. The type is `fractional`, which is probably a typedef (to a struct with numerator and denominator?).
The comments suggest that the data is stored in another memory space, perhaps some sort of Flash.

So the program seems to be for an embedded system.